# How to compute every sum for every argument a from an array of numbers A

Tags: numpy

I'd like to compute the following sums for each value of a in A:

```
D = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
A = np.array([0.5, 0.25, -0.5]) 
beta = 0.5

np.sum(np.square(beta) - np.square(D-a))
```

and the result is an array of all the sums. To compute it by hand, it would look something like this:

```
 [np.sum(np.square(beta)-np.square(D-0.5)), 
  np.sum(np.square(beta)-np.square(D-0.25)),
  np.sum(np.square(beta)-np.square(D-0.5))]
```

Comment: Welcome! What did you try? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: hi, it's pseudo code describing my intent to go through each a in A while computing the sums to produce the final example i've given. There is no way to write it literally, so i'm asking about the trick which would allow it be written in numpy. Have got an answer below but i'm not sure if this trick is the best way to do this sort of thing in the first place or if there is a better way.

Answer (score 1):

Use `np.sum` with broadcasting

```
np.sum(np.square(beta) - np.square(D[None,:] - A[:,None]), axis=1)

Out[98]: array([-20.  , -24.25, -40.  ])
```

---

**Explain**: We need the whole array D subtracts each element of array A. We can't simple call `D` - `A` because it just does subtraction element-wise between `D` and `A`. Therefore, we need employing numpy broadcasting. We need to add an additional dimension to `D` and `A` to satisfy rules of broadcasting. After that, just do calculation and `sum` them along axis=1

**Step by step**:
Increase dimension `D` from `1D` to `2D` at axis=0

```
In [10]: D[None,:]
Out[10]: array([[1, 2, 3, 4]])

In [11]: D.shape
Out[11]: (4,)

In [12]: D[None,:].shape
Out[12]: (1, 4)
```

Doing the same for `A`, but at axis=1

```
In [13]: A[:,None]
Out[13]: 
array([[ 0.5 ],
       [ 0.25],
       [-0.5 ]])

In [14]: A.shape
Out[14]: (3,)

In [15]: A[:,None].shape
Out[15]: (3, 1)
```

On subtraction, numpy broadcasting kicks in to broadcast each array to compatible dimension and does subtraction to create 2D array result

```
In [16]: D[None,:] - A[:,None]
Out[16]:
array([[0.5 , 1.5 , 2.5 , 3.5 ],
       [0.75, 1.75, 2.75, 3.75],
       [1.5 , 2.5 , 3.5 , 4.5 ]])
```

Next, it is just element-wise `square` and subtraction and `square`.

```
np.square(beta) - np.square(D[None,:] - A[:,None])

Out[17]:
array([[  0.    ,  -2.    ,  -6.    , -12.    ],
       [ -0.3125,  -2.8125,  -7.3125, -13.8125],
       [ -2.    ,  -6.    , -12.    , -20.    ]])
```

Lastly, sum alongs axis=1 to get the final output:

```
np.sum(np.square(beta) - np.square(D[None,:] - A[:,None]), axis=1)

Out[18]: array([-20.  , -24.25, -40.  ])
```

You may read docs on numpy broadcasting here to get more info https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html

Comment: thank you so much. Can you tell me why that works? It seems like magic.

Comment: Last question, if I were to write code like this in production (for a lack of a better word) - would it be frowned upon or is this considered idiomatic?

Comment: @ruzq: It is better to break this one-liner into several lines for better code debugging and maintenance. Some companies may have coding guidance in limiting number of nesting function calls and loops. In this case, it nests 3 levels. I think 2 level nesting is common guidance. In collaborate codes, you may change `None` to `np.newaxis` to make it more verbose and clear. Pandas bases on python and python zen is `Explicit is better than implicit` and `Flat is better than nested`.  (Note, `nested` is different from `chain`. Pandas encourages `chain`)

Comment: L i still feel completely lost. Now i'm making beta take on a number of different values so i can do sums for each different beta as well as every alpha .. feels like this is insurmountable to understand it through broadcasting alone. I want to go back to something that feels safer and more predictable with looping and indices etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too familiar with numpy, so there may be a vectorized way to do this. But with list comprehension, this will do:

```
[ np.sum(np.square(beta) - np.square(D-a)) for a in A ]
```

Output:

```
[-20.0, -24.25, -40.0]
```

Comment: That's cool, I didn't think of that. I'm trying to learn the idiomatic way to do it using numpy, i think Andy L. has given it above.